# Plain text password vs autologin

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A customer of ours complained about login password recovery using plain text password. The only workaround I know is auto-login with encripted username and passord in the query string.

What other options exist to increase the password recovery security?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to sending them their current password in plaintext, or generating a new password and sending that?

Comment: What is password recovery security? Why do passwords need to be recovered?

Comment: @Brandon: I meant current password.

Answer (score 2):

You can send them a URL that lets them reset the password themselves.

You could create a database table that stores, at the very minimum, a user id and a hash value.

Send the user a link that includes the hash, and on the receiving page look up the associated information and allow the user to reset the password to the account. Which I'm hoping you store in the database as a hash value. Plain text passwords should never be stored or sent out.

Just be sure that the link either expires or is deactivated once the password is changed. Otherwise someone could visit that link whenever they want and change the password.

Comment: In other words, it's never a good idea to store the plain text password anywhere.

Comment: Interesting, yes we use ASP.NET MVC 3 standard membership and it's encripted passwords. Is it something ASP.NET MVC 3 provides simply changing some parameters?

Comment: Yes, you can configure the default membership provider to use hashed rather than encrypted passwords. You have to set `enablePasswordRetrieval="false"` and `enablePasswordReset="true"`. You can also set `passwordFormat="Hashed"`

Comment: @Brandon: We use hashed password. I meant, if I can configure ASP.NET MVC3 membership to allow `send them a URL that lets them reset the password themselves ... be sure that the link either expires or is deactivated once the password is changed`

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines as Brandon's excellent answer, here is what we do:

1. Do not store passwords in plain text, or even a decryptable value. Always store passwords using a 1-way hashing algorithm. This means only the user can ever know what the plain-text password is.
2. When a user forgets their password, present them with a form where they enter their email address, and click submit.
3. When they submit their email address, create a table row with 2 major pieces: The first is a password reset token (we use a Guid for this). The token should be timestamped, so that you know when it was created, and when it expires (ours expire within 2 hours of submission). The second piece is a secret code that the user will have to enter in order to reset their password.
4. Send an email to the user, with a link to a page that will accept the token and secret code. When they click the link (or visit the page and enter the code manually), you can then present them with a page that lets them change their password without knowing its previous value.

Using a time-constrained token is a good idea, because if the user's email account is later compromised, the criminals can't use the email to reset the password -- assuming of course that the email account is not compromised within 2 hours of the password reset request.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't send out the actual password of the account in plain text to the user's email address.  The reason for this is because if someone hacked the users email address now they have their actual password.  Most likely this password will be used for other systems as well.

The alternative is to send an encrypted querystring that links to that user and allow them to change their password based on some sort of security question or demographics you have specific to that user.

Facebook uses a matching of friends images to names.  If you have their DOB and address you could use that (not that secure).  Or you could set up specific security question and answers which would be better.

Comment: A plain text version of the password should not even be available in the database to send out to a user. Authentication should use a one-way hash to verify the password against the database.